# How to extract values from JSONArray object from JSON response in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a problem in extracting JSONObject from Array. This is JSON response. I want to extract values from it. Now I have to read "name" property value from time JSONArray and label property value from "Azure-Services" JSONArray.

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "time": [
        {
          "name": "total",
          "label": "Total"
        },
        {
          "excluded": false,
          "parent": -1,
          "name": "2022-01",
          "direct": null,
          "populated": true,
          "label": "2022-01",
          "sort_order": null,
          "extended": false
        },
        {
          "excluded": false,
          "parent": -1,
          "name": "2022-02",
          "direct": null,
          "populated": true,
          "label": "2022-02",
          "sort_order": null,
          "extended": false
        },
        {
          "excluded": false,
          "parent": -1,
          "name": "2022-03",
          "direct": null,
          "populated": true,
          "label": "2022-03",
          "sort_order": null,
          "extended": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Azure-Services": [
        {
          "name": "total",
          "label": "Total"
        },
        {
          "excluded": null,
          "parent": -1,
          "name": "1700",
          "direct": null,
          "populated": null,
          "label": "Marketplace",
          "sort_order": null,
          "extended": false
        },
        {
          "excluded": null,
          "parent": 0,
          "name": "1701",
          "direct": false,
          "populated": null,
          "label": "Marketplace",
          "sort_order": null,
          "extended": false
        },
        {
          "excluded": null,
          "parent": -1,
          "name": "3000",
          "direct": null,
          "populated": null,
          "label": "Storage",
          "sort_order": null,
          "extended": false
        },
        {
          "excluded": null,
          "parent": -1,
          "name": "azure_other",
          "direct": null,
          "populated": null,
          "label": "Other",
          "sort_order": null,
          "extended": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want time and Azure-Services object separately. I tried this way:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(reportData);
System.out.println("Json Object = "+jsonObj);
JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("dimensions");
System.out.println("Dimension array = "+jsonArr); // dimensions object response is shown above
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("JSON Array : "+jsonArr.getJSONObject(i));;
    // how to iterate in for loop to get time and azure services seperately.
}
```

Now, I want to iterate time array and Azure-Services array object to get property's value.

How should I do that?

Comment: Do it in the exact same way. `jsonArr.getJSONObject(i)` is a `JSONObject`, if you call `getJSONArray("time")` on it, you get the `JSONArray` behind the `time` key.

Comment: You mean like this 
System.out.println("JSON Array : "+jsonArr.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("time"));

Comment: yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I retrieved time array separately. Now I want label value from each iteration of time Array.

Comment: Then iterate over the array. Your code alrady has a loop that iterates over an array. The code is right there, just use it.